# Удаление всех терминов, включая дефолтный, из таксономии category

Tags: wordpress

Существует ли в Wordpress законный способ удаления всех категорий, включая рубрику по умолчанию?

`wp_delete_category(1);`, `wp_delete_term(1, 'category');` ожидаемо возвращают `0`

Comment: Законного удаления *всех* РУБРИК быть не может по архитектуре ВП. Но это и незачем в общем-то.

Comment: в WP нет такой возможности, вы можете назначить другую рубрику в качестве дефолтной и удалить старую. Или если вопрос в seo то настроить robots.txt, а при заходе на страницу рубрики отдавать 404 ответ или редиректить на нужную страницу.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_terms для получения списка терминов и https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_delete_term для их удаления

Насколько мне известно, стандартной функции для этого нет

Comment: Тут вопрос в основном в удалении дефолтной рубрики, которая приезжает, что называется, в коробке. WP не позволяет удалить её из админки или предназначенными для удаления терминов функциями. В принципе всегда можно пойти прямо в БД и удалить записи в таблицах терминов, но интересно, есть ли более мягкие способы

Comment: То что «приезжает в коробке» например “Uncategorized” удалить можно, но сначала нужно создать новую рубрику, назначить её главной, а потом удалить uncategorized, а лучше просто переименовать и не париться. По умолчанию тема в любом случае должна быть - это неизбежно, чтоб посты не валялись непонятно где